# Ruby Cannot Convert Hash Into Int

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby bash script to download a zip file and output a progress bar to the stdout. I have the following

```
# Temp file name
tmp = ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(8)
file = temp_dl_dir+tmp+'.zip'

print file.inspect

# Download
progress_bar = nil
open(file, 'w', :content_length_proc => lambda { |length|
  if length && 0 < length
    progress_bar = ProgressBar.new('...', length)
    progress_bar.file_transfer_mode
  end 
},
:progress_proc => lambda { |progress|
  progress_bar.set(progress) if progress_bar
}) do |fo|
    fo.print open(dl).read
end
```

But when I run it I get

```
open-uri.rb:32:in `initialize': can't convert Hash into Integer (TypeError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `open_uri_original_open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:32:in `open'
    from ./site.rb:191 (line 191 is the open(file, 'w' ...) one)
```

Which means there is a problem with my `open(file, 'w' ...` function

I can't figure out what's wrong +_+

Comment: I was just about to ask the same thing. Which line is the stack trace complaining about?

Comment: Line 191 is the open(file, 'w', ...) one... Line 32 is `def is_dir?(directory)`

Comment: Oh I wonder if the problem is with the third argument in open? The third argument in open is ":content_length_proc => lambda..." which is a hash. The stack trace is talking about open-uri.rb:32. So maybe that call to open is expecting the third argument to be an Int.

Comment: is_dir? has nothing to do with this, the 32 is open-uri.rb line 32, do you want me to post open-uri.rb gem code? I can do that if you want, but I didn't write it. The proble is line 191, which is the open(file, 'w' line

Comment: @NiklasB.: The error that the stack trace mentions is not in his file. It is in open-uri.rb which is a ruby lib for opening a file at a URI.

Comment: Does this code work if you get rid of the two lambda args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:content_length_proc` appears to be related to `OpenURI::OpenRead#open`. (Check by `ri open` then search for `:content_length_proc`.)

My `ri` documentation on this method says:

> However, `mode` must be read mode because `OpenURI::OpenRead#open` doesn't support
>   write mode (yet). Also `perm` is ignored because it is meaningful only for file
>   creation.

So you cannot use `OpenURI::OpenRead#open` with `'w'` mode. You must either use a different mechanism to write to your URL if that is your actual goal. (Your English description says you're trying to *download* a file, but you wouldn't be using `'w'` mode to the `OpenURI::OpenRead#open` method in that case...)